# Display vertical scrollbar in DataGridView without resizing columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, resize, scrollbar

I have a `DataGridView`, and when there are enough rows the vertical scroll bar appears.

My problem is that the scrollbar takes up room inside the `DataGridView`, causing my columns to resize. Is there a property which forces the scrollbar to be placed to the right of the `DataGridView` (so my column sizes remain intact)?

The only other thing I could think of would be to programmatically resize the `DataGridView` when the scrollbar is added (in which case, is there an event which is triggered when this happens?)

Comment: Does the resizing still occur when you give the columns fixed widths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't.

But you can set the DataGridView.ScrollBars property to horizontal only and create your own scrollbar outside the DataGridView.

You'll need to update the min/max values of the external scrollbar on the databinding event of the gridview.

And when you receive a scrollevent from your external scrollbar your can let your DataGridView scroll by setting the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but thanks for the tip on using an external scrollbar, need to decide if I think it's worth the effort!